# Understanding Ramsey's theorem in the context of Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I read the following proof which apparently is a "Version of Ramsey's Theorem":

Let $S$ be a collection of $k$-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed. Then there is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ denoted by $L$ such that either

Every $k$-element subset of $L$ belongs to $S$

or

Every $k$-element subset of $L$ is not in $S$

I have been asked to prove that every sequence of real numbers has a monotone subsequence using this theorem. However I don't really understand the theorem. I tried to understand by creating an example. Say I have a collection $S = \{\;\{x,x+2,x+4\}\ | \; x \text{ is even}\;\}$. Then I have a collection of $3$-element sets all containing even numbers. By the theorem, it's guaranteed that there is some infinite set $L$ whose collection of $3$-element subsets either contain all or none of the sets in $S$. An example of $L$ in this case would be the set of all odd numbers.

Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Not quite. The theorem says there is an $L$ such that either all or none of the $3$-element subsets of $L$ belong to $S$. In (non-standard, but hopefully understandable in the context) symbols: There is an $L$ such that either $\mathcal{P}_k(L) \subset S$ or $\mathcal{P}_k(L) \cap S = \varnothing$. Do you know which $k$ to take to prove the existence of monotone subsequences?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for clearing it up. Initially I tried with $k = 1$ but I didn't get very far.

Comment: Then try $k = 2$. That should get you farther.

Comment: @DanielFischer I gave it a shot with $k=2$ and answered my own question. However I feel like I just tried to awkwardly shoehorn the proof that I already know into another form to fit Ramsey's theorem. Please let me know if I'm at least heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are understanding it right. You didn't *say* it right. You said: there is some infinite set $L$ whose collection of $3$-element sets either
(1) contains all of the sets in $S$, or else
(2) contains none of the sets in $S$.

Condition (1) as stated is trivial: just take $L=\mathbb N$; the collection of $3$-element subsets of $\mathbb N$ certainly contains all the sets in $S$. You have the inclusion the wrong way round, but maybe that was just a slip.

It's easier to state with a bit of notation. Let $\binom Xk$ denote the collection of all $k$-element subsets of a set $X.$ Ramsey's theorem says that, for any collection $S\subseteq\binom{\mathbb N}k,$ there is an infinite set $L\subseteq\mathbb N$ such that either $\binom Lk\subseteq S$ or else $\binom Lk\cap S=\emptyset$; in other words, either $\binom Lk\subseteq S$ or else $\binom Lk\subseteq\binom{\mathbb N}k\setminus S.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the collection of sets of the form $\{n_i,n_{i+1}\}$. $n_i$ is an index of $(x_n)$ where $x_{n_i}$ is followed by a subsequent term which is greater. $n_{i+1}$ is the index of the first-appearing greater subsequent term.

Case 1: The collection of all $2$-element subsets in $L$ belong to $S$. In which case $S$ is infinite. I take each second term from $\{n_1,n_2\}$, $\{n_2,n_3\}$, $\{n_3,n_4\}$ and so on. Then I can make $\{n_1, n_2, n_3,...\}$ as a monotonically increasing infinite sequence.

Case 2: no $2$-element subsets of $L$ belong to $S$. In which case $S$ must be finite, that is there must be a final subset $\{n_k, n_{k+1}\}$ in $S$. Therefore there must be a subsequent term $n_{k+2} \leq n_{k+1}$ Since no further term is greater than $ n_{k+1}$. This logic can be followed infinitely many times to get a monotonically decreasing subsequence $\{n_{k+1}, n_{k+2}, n_{k+3},...\}$.

Comment: It's the right direction, but you're not quite there. In case 1, how do you know that for every $\{n1,n_2\} \in S$ there is a pair $\{n_2,n_3\}\in S$? (That need not be the case.) In case 2, it does not follow that $S$ must be finite. I'm not sure that you can complete the argument with the $S$ you chose, though I would guess you can. However, you get a nicer proof if you take a different (larger) set $S$.

Comment: Namely, $S = \bigl\{ \{k,n\} : k,n \in \mathbb{N},\; k < n,\; x_k < x_n\bigr\}$.

Comment: I think I can solve it from that choice of $S$, thank you for the help.